# How to set heading or field label for list view in GXT.?

Tags: gxt

I'm new to GXT, I'm developing a project by using GXT 2.0.1. I want to set field label for a list view. How to set field label.?

```
ListView<Stock> list2 = new ListView<Stock>();
    list2.setDisplayProperty("name");
    store = new ListStore<Stock>();
    store.setStoreSorter(new StoreSorter<Stock>());
    list2.setStore(store);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `ListView` in a [`ContentPanel`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/ContentPanel.html) and then set the heading:

```
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
cp.setHeading("Stocks");
cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());
cp.add(list2);
add(cp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ListField
Call setFieldLabel("name") on your field.
Make sure you add it to a container with a FormLayout.